# Azure WebJobs Multiinstances from Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, web-applications, servicebus

I am totally new to Azure World, so pardon me if the question looks silly.

We are building an Azure WEB APPS where the user can upload a text file. Once they finish uploading the text file, we write it to the Azure Service Bus Queue, saying the file is ready for processing.

We have a WebJob that runs continuously to pull the messages from the queue. If it sees a message in the ServiceBus Queue, it knows that it needs to process the file and does the work.

The files are pretty large and webjobs take couple of minutes to do the file manipulation and record in Azure SQL DB. What i am interested to Know here is, if multiple users load files at the same time and it gets added to the service bus queue, can the same webjobs be scaled up with multiple instances, so that the users dont need to wait for long time for their turn of processing the files. i.e. if 5 users load the file at same time, 5 messages are added to the service bus, can 5 instances of the same webjobs run at parallel, so there is no down time.

Answer (score 0):

[If your web app runs on more than one instance, a continuously running WebJob will run on all of your instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) More about instances [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/).

You can also use multiple threads to handle incoming messages like described [here](https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/performing-parallel-processing-in-azure-web-jobs/).